# jConfirm displaying [object Object] instead of string as message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jconfirm

I am using jConfirm to create a popup. I want it to display the message "Are you sure?" and the title "Confirm Deletion." The title works fine, and the callback works fine. But the message is displayed as `[object Object]`, and I cannot figure out why. I'm specifying a string as the message, so it shouldn't be getting confused.

This is the javascript generated by Rails:

```
<a onclick="deletePaymentMethod('3', 'gateway_bogus_3');" href="#"><img src="/assets/theme/admin/icons/delete.png" alt="Delete"> Delete</a>
```

And this the function in question:

```
function deletePaymentMethod(method, dom_id) {
   jConfirm('Are you sure?', 'Confirm Deletion', function(r) {
      if(r){
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: '/admin/payment_methods/' + method,
          data: ({_method: 'delete', authenticity_token: AUTH_TOKEN}),
          success: function(r){ $('#'+dom_id).fadeOut(); }
        });
       }
});
}
```

jConfirm is defined in jquery.alerts.js (https://github.com/caricorrejidor/jquery-alerts) as:

```
function(message, title, callback)
```

Additionally, I use jConfirm elsewhere in my codebase, and it works as expected.

ETA: I ended up just tweaking these lines in the library:

```
$("#popup_message").text(msg);
$("#popup_message").html( ("" + $("#popup_message").text()).replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );
```

I replaced it with this, and now everything is swell:

```
$("#popup_message").html( msg.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );
```

Comment: I tried it in a [code snippet](https://plnkr.co/edit/gjS0JPpnWhGp8ipUtWQJ?p=preview) and it worked. I just changed `jConfirm` to `$.alert`. Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: Actually, I get "$.alert is not a function".

Comment: Would you post a link to the library that you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/caricorrejidor/jquery-alerts

Comment: @blissfulchamois What is logged if you do `console.log($.fn.jquery);` ?

Comment: It prints "3.3.1"

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Here is a jsfiddle where I just copied the whole plugin (without change) below the function: https://jsfiddle.net/eun7xtg4/